# ASP.net MVC Tempdata getting DataSet's values out of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, tempdata

Hey all I am new to the MVC world and was wanting to get a few values from the TempData that I made that houses 3 DataSet's inside it.

The values that are inside the TempData are these:

[image]

then selecting tTrip then rows then Results View:

[image]

finally seeing the DataSet values for tTrip:

[image]

I populate the TempData like so (simplify):

```
allData.Merge("tEvents"); //Gathers data and places it into tEvents
allData.Merge("tTrip"); //Gathers data and places it into tTrip
allData.Merge("tExternalTrainingMain"); //Gathers data and places it into tExternalTrainingMain

TempData["jsonData"] = allData;
```

I've tried:

> string blah = TempData["jsonData"][0]["somename"].toString();
>
> string blah = TempData["jsonData"][0].somename.toString();
>
> string blah = TempData["jsonData"][0][0].somename.toString();
>
> string blah = TempData["jsonData"][0][0][0].toString();

But only get errors. What is the proper way of getting the dataset values out of the TempData array?

**UPDATE for DavidG**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [indexed property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.item(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Item(System.String)) that gives you the value from `TempData` returns a object of type `object`. You need to cast your value to the desired type. For example:

```
var myDataSet = TempData["jsonData"] as DataSet;
if(myDataSet != null)
{
    We have a dataset now!
    string blah = myDataSet.Tables[0]["somename"].toString();
}
```

Comment: hum I get the error **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataSet'** on the **myDataSet[0]** part?

Comment: You probably need the `Tables` property then, that's up to you really - I have no idea what your `DataSet` structure is.

Comment: I've updated my OP to show you the structure of the datasets within it.

Comment: You have your intellisense and debugging now, I'm not sure what else you want me to add now?

Comment: I can not seem to get past the first [0]. I try [0]["tTrip"] and that does not work. [0].tTrip and that also does not work... etc etc

Comment: Then your problem is with `DataSet`, not `TempData`.